# Solr 6.1 How to use PatternTokenizerFactory tokenizer get Number

Tags: solr, tokenize, analyzer

I need to analyze the text and get the number

1.e.g.  "acbt-10.2" => 10.2

2.e.g.  "acbt - 10.2" => 10.2

3.e.g.  "acbt" => 0

how to setting the pattern and group on PatternTokenizerFactory tokenizer for this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Add this fieldType to schema file. restart solr or reload core
and check on analyse page

```
<fieldType name="text_ptnreplace" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer>
         <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^0-9.]+" replacement="" replace="all"/>
       </analyzer>
     </fieldType>
```

Comment: This will not give 0 when no digits are present, so you probably want another filter to replace `""` with `"0"`.

Comment: I've try this, but is same, input => "acbt-10.2", output =>  "acbt-10.2", I need to output => 10.2

Comment: it's work by 
 <fieldType name="versions" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[^0-9.]+"/>   
  </analyzer>
 </fieldType>

Thanks~~~

Comment: `fieldType name="versions"`  you didn't mention name of fieldType in you question. so, I give example with different name.

Comment: I found another issue.... when  it intput => "acbt-11 sp1" the output=> 1,I think is because the second replace first ... how to make output to => 11?

Comment: output will be 111. with regex `"[^0-9.]+"` and add one more filter `<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="" replacement="0"/>`

Comment: If I just need the 11?